# Dynamic URL REWRITING for QueryStrings

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting, url-routing, url-mapping

hello please help me for this question

i have the following url --> www.sample.com/news.aspx?id=45

i want pass "id" in the query string to news.aspx and show this news, but due to url rewriting the url is changed to this --> www.sample.com/news/my-news-45/

How to extract "id" from the query string?

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can manually done URL rewriting but The downside of manually writing code   can be tedious and error prone.  Rather than do it yourself, I'd recommend using one of the already built HttpModules available on the web for free to perform this work for you.

Here a few free ones that you can download and use today:

http://urlrewriter.net/
http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter"  
             requirePermission="false" 
             type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
  </configSections>

  <system.web>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>

  </system.web>

  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/products/books.aspx" to="~/products.aspx?category=books" />
    <rewrite url="~/products/CDs.aspx" to="~/products.aspx?category=CDs" />
    <rewrite url="~/products/DVDs.aspx" to="~/products.aspx?category=DVDs" />
  </rewriter>  

</configuration>
```

The HttpModule URL rewriters above also add support for regular expression and URL pattern matching (to avoid you having to hard-code every URL in your web.config file).  So instead of hard-coding the category list, you could re-write the rules like below to dynamically pull the category from the URL for any "/products/[category].aspx" combination:

```
  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/products/(.+).aspx" to="~/products.aspx?category=$1" />
  </rewriter>
```

the complete reference can be found on this linke

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: thx for your answer but i want to give ID and replase url with title of news 

www.sample.com/news.aspx?TopicID=4 ---> www.sample.com/news/my-title-news/

can get me a simlpe project