# URL rewrite in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

i have a web site which will navigate to a different domain once logged in. I need to re write the url by removing the aspx page of the URL and add the domain name from which it navigates to. for eg:-from the site www.xyz.com it has been redirected to www.abc.com.so the url should be displayed as www.abc.com/xyz can anyone can help me on this?

Comment: www.abc.com is also your own domain ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422241/dynamic-url-rewriting-for-querystrings/6422336#6422336 here is the complete scene and its also as accepted answer dear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET URL Rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262/asp-net-url-rewriting)

Answer (score 0):

use a url re-writing tool

http://urlrewriter.net/

and have a look at this nice article from Scottgu also

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: could you please help me to write the url using the notations that they specified in web.config?                                  url="/tags/(.+)" rewrite="/tagcloud.aspx?tag=$1" in the same way how to rewrite the url from www.xyz.com to  www.xyz.com/abc